# Minimum of maximum with factorial

Tags: optimization, asymptotics, factorial, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

Let $f:\mathbb N_+\to\mathbb N_+, f(n)=\min\{\max\{k!,(n-k)!,(n!-k!(n-k)!)\}|k\in\mathbb N_+, n-k> 0,\ n!-k!(n-k)!> 0 \}$.

What's the asypmtotic growth of $f(n)$?

Is it true that $f(n)=\Theta((n/2)!)$?

Comment: "n!-k!(n-k)!>0" is always true as long as $0\lt k\lt n$.

Comment: Why didn't you accept the answer given?

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that $f(n)=\Theta((n/2)!)$.

$$\begin{aligned}
f(n)&=\min_{k\in\mathbb N_+, n-k> 0,\ n!-k!(n-k)!> 0}\{\max\{k!,\,(n-k)!,\,(n!-k!(n-k)!)\}\\
&=\min_{0\lt k\lt n}\{\max\{k!,\,(n-k)!,\,(n!-k!(n-k)!)\}\\
&=\min_{0\lt k\lt n}\{n!-k!(n-k)!\}\\
&=n!-\max_{0\lt k\lt n}\{k!(n-k)!\}\\
&=n!-1!(n-1)!\\
&=(n-1)(n-1)!\\
&=\omega((n/2)!)
\end{aligned}$$

In fact, $f(n)\sim n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\dfrac ne\right)^n$ by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).